# How to make assertRaises() print the passed *args, **kwargs in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertraises

I'm using `assertRaises` in a loop like this:

```
for i in ['a', 'b', 'c']: 
    self.assertRaises(ValidationError, my_method, i)
```

And the problem is that whenever test fails, the output looks like this:

```
  File "/bla/test.py", line 4, in test_assertion
      my_method(i)
AssertionError: ValidationError not raised
```

How to make it print out the value of `i` when test fails? Like this:

```
  File "/bla/test.py", line 4, in test_assertion
      my_method('b')
AssertionError: ValidationError not raised
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the ideal situation for the [`subTests`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#distinguishing-test-iterations-using-subtests) context manager. However, this is only available in python 3. I think the best solution would be to create your own version of `subTests`. The benefits being it's easy to setup a basic mimicry of `subTests`, and if `subTests` is ever back ported to python 2 then it will be easy to switch.

```
import unittest
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager

class TestCaseWithSubTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @contextmanager
    def subTest(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            yield None
        except:
            exc_class, exc, tb = sys.exc_info()
            kwargs_desc = ", ".join("{}={!r}".format(k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items())
            new_exc = exc_class("with {}: {}".format(kwargs_desc, exc))
            raise exc_class, new_exc, tb.tb_next

class MyTest(TestCaseWithSubTests):

    def test_with_assertion_error(self):
        for i in [0, 1]:
            with self.subTest(i=i), self.assertRaises(ZeroDivisionError):
                1 / i

    def test_with_value_error(self):
        def f(i):
            raise ValueError

        for i in [0, 1]:
            with self.subTest(i=i), self.assertRaises(ZeroDivisionError):
                f(i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Which produces the following output:

```
FE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_with_value_error (__main__.MyTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dunes\py2sub_tests.py", line 30, in test_with_value_error
    f(i)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\dunes\py2sub_tests.py", line 30, in test_with_value_error
    f(i)
  File "C:\Users\dunes\py2sub_tests.py", line 26, in f
    raise ValueError
ValueError: with i=0: 

======================================================================
FAIL: test_with_assertion_error (__main__.MyTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dunes\py2sub_tests.py", line 22, in test_with_assertion_error
    1 / i
  File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\dunes\py2sub_tests.py", line 22, in test_with_assertion_error
    1 / i
AssertionError: with i=1: ZeroDivisionError not raised

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.006s

FAILED (failures=1, errors=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, both your and @Sam solutions work for me, but this one looks clearer to me with one pep8 correction: in subTest method
`raise exc_class(new_exc)`

Comment: @3Gee I used the old style of raising an exception so as to preserve the traceback of the original exception. I'm work primarily with python 3, and this was the only way I could remember how to preserve a traceback in python 2. In python 3 I would have just written `raise new_exc from old_exc`.

Comment: actually (at least in my test cases) the traceback is preserved even without explicitly passing it like you did.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `assertRaises()` as a context manager.

```
with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
    my_method(i)
    print("Failed when i was",i)
```

The print statement will only execute when the `my_method()` line passes successfully, so it will appear as the output when your test fails. Bit of a hack, but it works (unless `my_method()` throws some error that is not a `ValidationError`).